# Nvidia driver not working on latest kernel (3.17) and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, compiling, nvidia

I'm pretty new to kernel hacking. However, I have built my own kernel before (3.16) and it works.

Now I tried upgrading to the latest kernel (3.17-rc7). I configure the kernel using the config file that has worked with my previous kernel (make olddefconfig) and build it with

```
make-kpkg -j4 --initrd kernel-image kernel-headers --append-to-version=mykern2
```

When I install the .deb package that comes out, I get some error messages related to nvidia drivers:

> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-rc7mykern2 (x86_64)
>   Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.38/build/make.log for more information.

The contents of this file are here: http://pastebin.com/HQHLh9LY . It says "nvidia.ko failed to build!" which seems pretty serious. Also, the error seems to come from including acpi/acpi.h somewhere in the code. I don't know where, though.

When I try to boot to my new kernel, I don't get past the login screen in Ubuntu. I give my password and the desktop just freezes. The mouse and keyboard still work but nothing appears on the desktop. Also the login screen seems to be in wrong resolution for my monitor.

How can I find out what exactly is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: The nvidia module should be built separate from the kernel build process, as 3.17 is telling you:  The header files used in the version of the nvidia driver are incompatible with the 3.17 Kernel, as a guess, but please read the make.log.  As such, upgrade the nvidia-driver or downgrade the kernel.

Comment: I tried upgrading the nvidia drivers from external sources. The end result was that everything got fucked up and I wasn't even able to use old nvidia drivers on older kernels anymore. I managed to fix this after three hours of work. If anyone has a way to make the latest kernel work on Ubuntu 14.04 with nvidia proprietary drivers, I'm interested.

Comment: I know how but it takes a weekend.